# Equivalent of substr for raw vectors

Tags: r, cran

Is there an equivalent of `substring` for `raw` vectors in `R`?

Say that I have a large binary raw vector `x`, e.g. as a result from reading a file using `readBin`. Now I used `grepRaw` to find the index of some fragment inside the raw vector that I would like to access. A toy example:

```
x <- charToRaw("foobar");
n <- 2;
m <- 5;
```

Now I would like to extract the "substring" from positions 2 and 5. A native way to do so is:

```
x[n:m]
```

However, this scales poorly for large fragments, because R first creates a large vector `n:m` and then iterates over this vector to extract the elements from `x` at these indices, one by one. Is there a more native method to extract a part of a `raw` vector, similar to `substr` for character vectors? I don't think I can use `rawToChar` because the files might contain non-text binary data.

Comment: An Rccp sugar implemetation of head / tail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a C implementation

```
library(inline)
subraw <- cfunction(c(x="raw", i="integer", j="integer"), "
    int n = INTEGER(j)[0] - INTEGER(i)[0] + 1;
    SEXP result;
    if (n < 0)
        Rf_error(\"j < i - 1\");
    result = Rf_allocVector(RAWSXP, n);
    memcpy(RAW(result), RAW(x) + INTEGER(i)[0] - 1L, n);
    return result;
")
```

with the usual caveats about missing sanity checks (e.g., i, j scalar and not NA, i > 0; j <= length(x), etc.). In action

```
> xx = readBin("~/bin/R-devel/lib/libR.so", raw(), 6000000)
> length(xx)
[1] 5706046
> length(subraw(xx, 1L, length(xx)))
[1] 5706046
> system.time(subraw(xx, 1L, length(xx)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.001
```

`subraw(xx, 10L, 9L)` returns `raw(0)`.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a native r-base solution, but this will do :)

Comment: This should really be adopted by base R.